# merge two lists with same number of records based in index c#

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have two classed mentioned below

```
public class NameDTO
{
    public string Name;
}

public class ValDTO
{
    public string Val;
}
```

For names i am getting list as shown in below image
[result for names list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM3Pc.png)

I am getting the result for values as shown in below image

[result of values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFwlO.png)

Both my list give a count of 96 values. I am trying to merge both results based on index position i.e. I am trying for a output as result of `listnames` first value to be matched with result of `listvalues`.

account-Ind : A... etc.

I tried

```
var objects = _nameDetials.Zip(_valDetials, (val, type) => Convert.ChangeType(val, type));
```

and

```
List<Object> allS = (from x in _nameDetials 
                     select (Object)new { 
                         someAnotherThing = x.Name, 
                         something = string.Empty }).ToList();

allS.AddRange((from x in _valDetials 
               select (Object)new { 
                   someAnotherThing = string.Empty, 
                   something = x.Val }).ToList());
```

Also I tried a lot of examples but could not come up with the output that I needed. I think there might a simple approach based on list indexes but I am unable to figure out exactly what is required.

Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have Lists or IEnumerables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have IEnumerables:

```
        IEnumerable<NameDTO> _nameDetials = new List<NameDTO>() { new NameDTO() { Name = "A" }, new NameDTO { Name = "B" } };
        IEnumerable<ValDTO> _valDetials=new List<ValDTO>() { new ValDTO() { Val = "1" }, new ValDTO() { Val = "2" } };

        var combined = _nameDetials.Zip(_valDetials, (name, val) => new KeyValuePair<NameDTO, ValDTO>(name, val));
```

Will return an IEnumerable of KeyValue pairs. You can replace with another type if you want, but this should help you see how to use Zip

Comment: The thing with Zip, is that the lambda you pass in, gets passed 2 parameters, 1 from each collection. You decide how you want to combine then. Think of it as Select for 2 simultaneous collections

Comment: Your code worked for me in getting my resultant output, but can you also help me in converting the same to json since I have found a lot of samples with 
KeyValuePair<string, object> 
for converting into json but could not find 
KeyValuePair<class,class>
Thanks